# SQL Server TIMESTAMP values OUTPUT parameters and ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ado.net, sqlcommand

Consider this simple SP:

```
create proc Updater
   @id int,
   @name varchar(25),
   @rowversion timestamp
  as
  begin
    update FOO
    set name=@name
    where id = @id and rowversion = @rowversion;

    if @@rowcount > 0
          select @rowversion = rowversion
          from FOO where id = @id;
    end
```

If someone else has edited the row since it was read in by a client app, this update will (intentionally) fail, because the timestamp which the client app is using has become stale.

Question for ADO.NET experts:  Does the @rowversion parameter have to be declared `OUTPUT` in the SP in order for the latest timestamp to be returned via the dataAdapter's UpdateCommand? Or will a default server-side parameter direction of IN return a value if the ADO.NET direction is set to `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`?

See this documentation of the [RowUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

**"If there are output parameters, they are placed in the DataRow."**

What does this ADO.NET document mean, precisely, by "output parameters"? Is it talking about the ADO.NET parameter definition, or the server-side definition, or both?

I don't want to rely upon my trial-and-error results since the behavior I'm seeing might be the result of some complicating factor I haven't identified yet.

Comment: `SP` return 0 or 1

Comment: I don't understand your comment, Sami. It doesn't seem to relate to the specific question I'm asking about *parameter* directionality.  I'm not asking about *return values*.

Comment: @Sami a stored procedure return value is an integer, not a not null bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this ADO.NET document mean, precisely, by "output
>   parameters"? Is it talking about the ADO.NET parameter definition, or
>   the server-side definition, or both?

Both

To receive output value you should specify direction (output or InputOutput) BOTH in SP definition and in your ADO.NET SqlCommand.

P.S. This behaviour is similar to `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
EXEC sp_executesql N'SET @i = @i+1', N'@i INT OUTPUT', @i OUTPUT
SELECT @i -- returns 2
```

Comment: Does T-SQL also support InputOutput? or just (default) IN or OUT?

Comment: All `OUTPUT` parameters in T-SQL are InputOuput. I've added example

Comment: Thanks, that last comment clarifies it all.